# ElasticSearch: Count number of documents in which a nested field occurs

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I have an index with documents of the form :

```
{
    "title": "Being John Malkovich",
    "credits": {
        "cast": [
            {
                "name": "Starring",
                "value": "John Malkovich"
            },
            {
                "name": "Supporting",
                "value": "John Cusack"
            }
        ],
        "crew": [
            {
                "name": "Directed",
                "value": "Spike Jonze"
            },
            {
                "name": "Written",
                "value": "Charlie Kauffman"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

(This is a contrived example but it follows the structure my company uses.)

What would be the terms aggregation needed to get a response of the form (**Assume 30 movie documents in total**):

```
{
  "number_of_documents_where_credits_field_exists": 30,
  "top_3_occurances_in_all_the_documents_of_any_cast_or_crew_member": [
    {
      "value": "Tom Cruise",
      "count": 10
    },
    {
      "value": "Spike Jonze",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "value": "John Malkovich",
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

where the results are sorted in descending order.

I am new to ES and was looking at Terms Aggregations but I am not sure how to write the equivalent of:

```
{
  "aggs":
      "top_3_occurances_in_all_the_documents_of_any_cast_or_crew_member":
         {
            <NESTED FIELD> : <CAST OR CREW MEMBER>
         }
}
```

where **NESTED FIELD** needs to take a nested field rather than a top level field like **"title"**. The results should display the top occurring **cast OR crew names.**

So far, as long as the request (using REST endpoints) contains the type of credit (say "cast") and the type of sub-credit (say "Starring"), I am able to create buckets and apply aggregations. For example, to know the top occurrences of **Starring cast** members, I had the following:

```
{
 "aggregations" : {
    "nestedagg" : {
      "nested" : {
        "path" : "credits.cast"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "filteredagg" : {
          "filter" : {
            "term" : {
              "credits.cast.name" : {
                "value" : "Starring",
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          },
          "aggregations" : {
            "termsagg" : {
              "terms" : {
                "field" : "credits.cast.value",
                "size" : 3,
                "shard_size" : -1,
                "min_doc_count" : 1,
                "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
                "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
                "order" : [
                  {
                    "_count" : "desc"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
   }
  }
```

which gave me (**assume only 20 movies have actors in starring roles and the rest are ensemble films with no starring actor**)

```
{
      "number_of_documents_where_credits.cast.Starring_exists": 20,
      "top_3_occurances_in_the_above_20_documents_of_a_starring_cast_member": [
        {
          "value": "Tom Cruise",
          "count": 10
        },
        {
          "value": "Seth Rogen",
          "count": 3
        },
        {
          "value": "Adam Sandler",
          "count": 1
        }
      ]
 }
```

Basically, I need to provide the most occurring cast or crew member names at a glance. This will be the default behavior if the client does not populate the credit type and sub-credit type.

Comment: I'm seeing that I probably need a reverse nested aggregation but I am struggling to get the syntax right. Any help is appreciated.